# Sort collection by first item of sub list in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, sorting

Is it possible to sort `IQueryable` collection by it's sub collections?

For example I have a `Books` collection. I also have an `Authors` collection which has a column `BookId`, so the `BookId` is a foreign key in `Authors` table. The relation is one-to-many (one book many authors).

I need to sort the `Books` collection by the first author. The book is not required to have an author. Can this be done in Entity Framework and Linq?

Comment: It's possible, but in database table the term **first** is undefined if you don't provide some explicit order. So you have to define which author is considered "first" and also what does order by author mean - e.g. by author Name etc.

Comment: The authors should be ordered by name, and the books collection by previously ordered list of authors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your concrete question (after clarification that *The authors should be ordered by name, and the books collection by previously ordered list of authors*) is like this:

```
var query = db.Books
    .OrderBy(b => b.Authors.OrderBy(a => a.Name).Select(a => a.Name).FirstOrDefault());
```

which would generate a single SQL query like this:

```
SELECT
    [Project2].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Project2].[Title] AS [Title]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
        [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title],
        (SELECT TOP (1) [Project1].[Name] AS [Name]
            FROM ( SELECT
                [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name]
                FROM [dbo].[Author] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[BookId]
            )  AS [Project1]
            ORDER BY [Project1].[Name] ASC) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Book] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Project2]
    ORDER BY [Project2].[C1] ASC
```

Note that the books w/o author will be the first in the order.

Another way is to use `Min` function:

```
var query = db.Books
    .OrderBy(b => b.Authors.Min(a => a.Name));
```

with SQL translation:

```
SELECT
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Project1].[Title] AS [Title]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
        [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title],
        (SELECT
            MIN([Extent2].[Name]) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Author] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[BookId]) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Book] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

Comment: This is the solution, basically @jdweng suggested the same just without Select(a => a.Name). The solution with Min is not working since some of the Authors collections can be empty.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;




namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Book> books = new List<Book>() {
               new Book() { name = "A", authors = new List<string>() { "AuthorA", "AuthorB","AuthorC"}},
               new Book() { name = "B", authors = new List<string>() { "AuthorD", "AuthorE","AuthorF"}},
               new Book() { name = "C", authors = new List<string>() { "AuthorG", "AuthorH","AuthorI"}},
               new Book() { name = "D", authors = new List<string>() { "AuthorJ", "AuthorK","AuthorL"}},
               new Book() { name = "E", authors = new List<string>() { "AuthorM", "AuthorN","AuthorO"}}
           };

            var orderedBook = books.OrderBy(x => x.authors.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Book
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<string> authors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is part of the solution. What if Author is object and we need to sort by Name property. We can use x.Authors.FirstOrDefault().Name but what if the collection is empty?

Comment: It will still sort with null being sort with the authors.  x.Authors.FirstOrDefault().Name does not make any sense.